# Can't install fast debugger at Netbeans 6.9.1 for ruby 2.2.3p173

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, ruby-debug, ruby-debug-ide

I'm trying to debug rails project ([redmine](https://github.com/redmine/redmine)) at Netbeans 6.9.1

When I click debug project I get the message:

[image]

When I click **Install Fast Debugger** I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/anatoly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/anatoly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/anatoly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/gem_make.out
```

`gem_make.out` not very informative and helpful for, at least for me:

```
/home/anatoly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake failed, exit code 1
```

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04.1` with `ruby 2.2.3p173` and `rails 4.2.4`

What may I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/ (not trolling, and no affiliation)

Comment: In general I agree with you but It's complicated right now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed manually `ruby-debug-ide` -v 0.4.33 gem and problem has been solved

`gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.4.33`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was also trying "manually" `gem install` but without version, it was getting v. 0.6.0, it was not working. I listed all versions (a bunch) and was just going to trial and error with the versions, but first I googled and found this. Saved me a lot of work!  (and it works with 0.4.33)

Answer (score 2):

`gem install ruby-debug-ide` will auto install ruby-debug-ide version 0.6, but netbeans 6.9.1 needs version 0.4.3.

`gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.4.33` should be successful.